# .net core when I read from appsettings, the sort is changed. Why?

Tags: sorting, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have this config in appsettings.json:

`"CategoriesTypes": [ "Country", "State", "Semester" ],`

in the code I read values like:

`var array = Configuration.GetSection("CategoriesTypes").AsEnumerable() .Where(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Value)).Select(o => o.Value).ToArray()`

// *output* of foreach loop:

"Semester", "State", "Country"

Why The sort is changed?

Answer (score -1):

`IEnumerable` do not pretend to keep items in order, unless you ask for. And as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-5.0)

> Methods that are used in a query that returns a sequence of values do not consume the target data until the query object is enumerated.

When you iterate through an `IEnumerable` it is just navigating to the previous/next item without knowing it in advance. So `IEnumerable` do not keep items sorted, because sorting requires to enumerate through the whole items in the list.

If you need to sort the list just use Linq extensions `OrderBy` or `OrdrByDescending` which will return `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: So. what can I do to keep the same sort?

Comment: @Munt, the best option is to add a sorting param to the list e.g. `[ "0:Country", "1:State", "2:Semester" ]` or `[ "0":"Country", "1":"State", "2":"Semester" ]` then you can use sort by. Or you may try use `IList` instead of `IEnumerable`, it should keep items order as it reads from the json.

Comment: @Munt, through linq's query and judgment, its order has been reversed. you can use Reverse.